# .h file in my Swift Framework

Tags: swift, frameworks

I am creating my first Swift framework and I notice there is a default .h file (Obj-C). What purpose does it serve in a Swift Framwork? Can it be removed without causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bridging header to make sure everything plays nice with Obj-C frameworks. You may be okay deleting it depending on the intended use of your framework, but it won't hurt anything to leave it in so that's what I would recommend for best practice and to make sure you don't accidentally break anything in different contexts that you use the framework in.